# Increment Interval - JS

Tags: javascript, setinterval, increment

This is probably well simple but I just can't work it out
When I run this...

```
function logCountUp(){
        let a = 0;
        while(a < 10)
        {
            a+=1;
            console.log(a);
        }
    }
    setInterval(logCountUp,2000);
```

it returns all numbers, 
I want each number every 2 seconds.
I tried wrapping the setInterval around the a++ but it then ignored the while.
It's proper stumped me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) repeatedly calls a function each period of time, so, in this case, when `a` reaches the max value (9), we stop the interval using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval):

```js
let a = 0;
const interval = setInterval(logCountUp, 2000);
function logCountUp() {
  a+=1; console.log(`${a}`);
  if(a === 9) clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: So 'set' and 'clear' are kinda like 'start' and 'stop'??

Comment: Yes, ``set`` starts executing the function on intervals, and ``clear``stops this behavior

Comment: Sorry yo, it's not really a question or anything, but I just realised the thing the threw me off about your answer: it runs the function and declares the constant at the same time. Weird stuff.

Comment: Yes, in JavaScript you can save the function called (``setInterval`` for example) in a variable to be passed later here to the ``clearInterval`` and stop it

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening right now :-

```
function logCountUp(){
        let a = 0;
        while(a < 10)
        {
            a+=1;
            console.log(a);
        }
    }
    setInterval(logCountUp,2000);
```

Your function `logCountUp` gets called every two seconds but you have a local variable `a` which everytime gets initialized to 0 and runs through that while loop and prints all the results.

What you need is a global variable which you keep incrementing inside your functional call every two seconds. Once it reaches the threshold (i.e 10) you clear the interval.

This is what you want :-

```js
let count = 0;
function logCountUp(){
        if(count < 10)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else{
         clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }
    let interval = setInterval(logCountUp,2000);
```

Comment: ah thanks so much, yeah, I think I prefer this syntax.  More long winded, but slightly easier to follow for a beginner like myself.